# What is the difference between g++.exe and x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe?

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, x86-64, mingw-w64

Same question goes for gcc, ar, etc. as well.

On changing the toolchain executable from something.exe to x86_64-w64-mingw32-something.exe in Code::Blocks, the code still compiles perfectly. Also, both 32-bit and 64-bit modes work perfectly in both the cases.

`g++ -v` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -v` show the same output on command line.

If these are exactly the same, why are they provided as different executables?

Comment: if your program is written in standard c++ you can use any c++ compliant compiler and the code will still compile perfectly, that does not necessarily imply that the compilers are exactly the same

Comment: Did you just compare 2 versions of a compiler on the metric that it compiles code correctly? That would be on the same level of usefulness as comparing 2 cars on the fact that they can drive.

Comment: I can't understand how are these executables different. Hence the question.

Comment: Run them both with `-v` and edit the results into your question.  `g++ -v` vs. `x86_64-w64-mingw32-something.exe -v` with no other args shows you some info about how each was configured, and what version of gcc it is.

Comment: I am not judging the compilers to be the same. The question asks for what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Maybe also look at a hello-world.exe from each, and see if they link different libraries or otherwise make different executables.

Comment: One might be the default compiler for your system, and the other one for compiling to a specific target. If the "specific target" happens to be the same as the system you are using, they might be identical. Otherwise not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731495/can-anyone-explain-the-gcc-cross-compiler-naming-convention  on a linux system g++ would most likely by a symbolic link to the __native-native__ version of the compiler.  MS Windows does not have convenient symbolic soft links so more than one file is provided.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @RichardCritten.

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi not really unless you have a specific question did you read the link ?

Comment: Your edit (removing a specific question) made the question less answerable.  Or did it turn out that they're *not* the same executable?  If they're different, prove it with `md5sum` or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I understand that inclusion of that question can lead to some people believing that I am (wrongly) equating the compilers based on the fact that they both can compile as is the case in some of the previous comments. By the way, I got the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe is a cross compiler, for compiling code that can run on a different type of computer than the one it was compiled on (based on the name, it looks like Windows 64-bit).  g++ is the regular compiler, for compiling code to run on the same computer or same type of computer.  On your system (e.g. if your system is 64-bit Windows) it's possible that they do the same thing.