# How can I compile using g++ in a 32 bit operating system

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I am new to c++ and I am using g++ 10.2.0 in the windows 7 32 bit operating system. And I got this g++ from http://winlibs.com/   and I downloaded it and add it to my Codeblocks IDE. This website is saying that I have to put `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` in my compiler because I'm using 32-bit operating systems. It means it is the compiler for the 32-bit operating system. But when I want to compile using `windows command prompt`  and when I use `g++ -o prog1 prog1.cc` to compile a file named prog1 in a directory, then it compiles the file. So, my question is, shouldn't I put the `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` because it is my compiler for 32 bit? And why is the `g++ -o prog1 prog1.cc` working in my software?

Comment: What does `g++ --version` print?

Comment: It prints 10.2.0 and before this there is some texts.

Comment: Use cmake for building and I can recommend to use the MSVC on windows,  the gcc on linux and clang on mac. I can not recommend mingw.

Comment: I have a found a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324337/what-is-the-difference-between-g-exe-and-x86-64-w64-mingw32-g-exe/ but I can't understand what they meant. So, can someone explain what thet meant?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded 32-bit MinGW-w64 GCC from http://winlibs.com/ then `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` and `g++.exe` are the same thing.
GCC has a convention where target compilers have a full name of TARGET+`-g++.exe` so compilers for different targets can coexist. But here the native platform is the target so `g++.exe` is the same compiler as `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`.

So running `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -o prog1 prog1.cc` will give you the same result.

Make sure in Code::Blocks to also set "Compiler's installation directory" to the folder containing `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`, otherwise Code::Blocks will not know where to find the file.