# How does a debugger identify a thread?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb, zephyr-rtos

When using a debugger to debug a mutli-thread application, the debugger usually shows the currently running threads. Either with some GUI or command like `info threads`.

But thread is an OS-specific concept. Though logically similar, each OS has a different implementation of thread.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731708/264052), gcc toolchain has the naming convention like this:

```
arch-vendor-(os-)abi
```

For example:

- arm-none-linux-gnueabi  (ARM toolchain for linux)
- arm-none-eabi (ARM toolchain for bare-metal systems)

The `arm` part obviously shows that a debugger is architecture-specific. And there can be an **optional** part to specify OS.

Does a debugger need to have the intimate knowledge of the OS to understand the thread details *for that OS*? i.e. the debugger is showing **software thread**.

Or does the debugger just treat each processor core as a thread? i.e. the debugger is showing **hardware thread**. This approach seems more generic because it can work for different OSes on a same hardware architecture.

When I used some Zephyr RTOS specific gdb to connect to a board running Zephyr, I noticed it shows below information at the start.

[image]

So it seems the debugger does have some built-in knowledge for several RTOSes.

Is this for some OS-specific things like thread details? Or something else?

### ADD 1 - 3:44 PM 5/1/2022

(Some understanding based on `Employed Russian`'s reply.)

Quote from the [libthread_db](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/817-5435/6mkt2tq8a/index.html):

> libthread_db is dependent on the internal implementation details of
> libthread. It is a "friend" of libthread in the C++ sense, which is
> precisely the "value added" by libthread_db. **It encapsulates the
> knowledge of libthread internals that a debugger needs in order to
> manipulate the threads-related state of a target process.**

So the `libthread` hides the thread implementation details of the underlying OS. And a debugger for that OS can leverage it.

As to below one:

> ### Or does the debugger just treat each processor core as a thread? i.e.
> the debugger is showing hardware thread. This approach seems more
> generic.
>
> No. Such approach would be entirely inadequate for debugging (you
> could have a multi-threaded program running on a single-core system).

It seems the debugger should be nice enough to provide some software thread abstraction to ease the debugging. But I think that can only be done for some well-known OSes. What if I wrote a unique OS that only I know the threading internals? Is that the **bare-metal debugger** such as `arm-none-eabi (ARM toolchain for bare-metal systems)`for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a debugger need to have the intimate knowledge of the OS to understand the thread details for that OS?

Not necessarily. The debugger could leverage [libthread_db](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/817-5435/6mkt2tq8a/index.html) (part of the thread library implementation) which supplies the details of that particular implementation.

> i.e. the debugger is showing software thread.

Yes.

> Or does the debugger just treat each processor core as a thread? i.e. the debugger is showing hardware thread. This approach seems more generic.

No. Such approach would be entirely inadequate for debugging (you could have a multi-threaded program running on a single-core system).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my question. Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @smwikipedia " Is that the bare-metal debugger ... for?" -- I don't know -- I've never worked on a bare-metal system.