# Could not find configuration file /etc/startup.mk

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I want to develop a simple C application for learning purposes using Eclipse (Juno) CDT.

For that, I created the sample project provided in the IDE that creates a simple Hello World executable.

But when I want to build the project, the following errors comes up:

```
make: all
make: Error -- Could not find configuration file /etc/startup.mk
```

What does this mean? I can't find a file named like this anywhere on my system. Curiously enough, it works on my OS X with the same setup perfectly. Just not on my Windows machine.

What is going wrong here?

Edit: `make -V` show the following output:

```
D:\>make -V
make - Version 7.0 build 1182

Built-in Rules (cannot be changed):
        OS:=NT
        .IMPORT .IGNORE : ROOTDIR
        .MAKEFILES:makefile
        .SOURCE : .NULL
        @B = $(@:b)
        @D = $(@:d)
        @F = $(@:f)
        %B = $(%:b)
        %D = $(%:d)
        %F = $(%:f)
        *B = $(*:b)
        *D = $(*:d)
        *F = $(*:f)
        <B = $(<:b)
        <D = $(<:d)
        <F = $(<:f)
        ?B = $(?:b)
        ?F = $(?:f)
        ?D = $(?:d)
System Configuration:
        SWITCHAR = /
        OSVERSION = 01
        OSRELEASE = 5
        DIRSEPSTR = /\:
        SHELL = /mksnt/sh.exe
        SHELLFLAGS = /c
        SHELLMETAS =
        GROUPSHELL = /mksnt/sh.exe
        GROUPFLAGS =
        GROUPSUFFIX =
        MAKEDIR = D:/
        PWD = D:/
```

Comment: Maybe, the wrong `make` executable is invoked. When you do `make --version` from the prompt, what does it show?

Comment: `make --version` isn't recognized, but `make -V` show the output I edited into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `make` executable that is in your path is not the GNU make that `eclipse` expects and needs. It is probably a tool that comes with some other product -- `make` is a pretty common name. If your windows is not too old, you could try `where make` to locate the culprit and remove it from your path. Once you have done that, eclipse will be able to the GNU make by itself if you used the standard installation of your toolchain, or you could add it to your path. Alternatively, you can customize the eclipse build settings and explicitly point it to the `make` you want to use.

The `make` you want is probably in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`, but could be somewhere else depending on how you installed the toolchain. There is also a `mingw32-make` in `C:\MinGW\bin` -- all assuming that you are using MinGW

Comment: `where make` isn't available in my command line. Is there another way to find out where the make originates?

Comment: Check out http://ss64.com/nt/where.html, there is a number of links on the bottom in the "Related" section that can help you with this.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I discovered that the make comes from MKS Integrity... So I installed MinGW and eclipse recognized it automatically as a new toolchain! Big thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure. FYI: depending on what you are planning to do, you might also consider using cygwin in stead of MinGW. See [What is the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/771756/1380680) for some discussion