# Msys compile of C code

Tags: c, mingw, msys

I'm not very familiar with compiling C code, especially on Windows using MinGW/Msys.  Here is my problem.  I am attempting to compile an open-source M3u8-segmenter C code for Windows.  The open-source examples all deal with linux, but I have successfully compiled the code on my Mac OSX machine without a problem.

In Msys on Windows, the `./configure` is successful, but once I do the Make, I get the following error.  It appears to related to the signal.h include, but I'm not sure. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/install/m3u8-segmenter-master/tests'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/install/m3u8-segmenter-master/tests'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/install/m3u8-segmenter-master'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"m3u8-segmenter\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"m3u8-segmenter\" -DPAC
KAGE_VERSION=\"0.3\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"m3u8-segmenter\ 0.3\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPOR
T=\"http://github.com/johnf/m3u8-segmenter/issues\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"http://m3u8-
segmenter.inodes.org\" -DPACKAGE=\"m3u8-segmenter\" -DVERSION=\"0.3\" -DSTDC_HEA
DERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_
H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -
DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SIGNAL_H=1 -DHAVE_GETOPT_H=1 -DHAVE
_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_STRRCHR=1 -D
HAVE_STRTOL=1 -I.    -Ic:/msys/1.0/local/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclar
ation-after-statement -Wpointer-arith -funsigned-char -Werror -Wall -Wstrict-pro
totypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wneste
d-externs -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings  -MT m3u8_segmenter-m3u8-
segmenter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/m3u8_segmenter-m3u8-segmenter.Tpo -c -o m3u8_segme
nter-m3u8-segmenter.o `test -f 'm3u8-segmenter.c' || echo './'`m3u8-segmenter.c
m3u8-segmenter.c: In function 'main':
m3u8-segmenter.c:212:22: error: storage size of 'act' isn't known
m3u8-segmenter.c:413:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'sigaction' [-We
rror=implicit-function-declaration]
m3u8-segmenter.c:413:5: error: nested extern declaration of 'sigaction' [-Werror
=nested-externs]
m3u8-segmenter.c:212:22: error: unused variable 'act' [-Werror=unused-variable]
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors

make[1]: *** [m3u8_segmenter-m3u8-segmenter.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/install/m3u8-segmenter-master'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: "I'm not very familiar with compiling C code, especially on Windows" - nobody can be familiar with that, by definition, don't feel bad :P

Comment: Looks like there is some platform specific incompatibility. It is most likely in header file included before signal.h. Switching order of include files may help too.

Comment: @hyde: If switching the order of the `#include` directives helps, it probably indicates a problem with the headers. Each header should `#include` everything it needs.

Answer (score 0):

To emulate UNIX on Windows, Cygwin is more appropriate than MSys/MinGW as pointed by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw)