# MinGW or Cygwin GCC?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I want to install a GCC compiler in Windows for the Eclipse IDE. I know there are two options: MinGW GCC or Cygwin GCC. Which one is better for Eclipse CDT? Any experience or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Use whatever you like. I would recommend to go for MinGW, this way you will avoid annoying cygwin1.dll dependency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Cygwin means your program will be dependent on `cygwin1.dll`, which is essentially a layer that allows POSIX functionality to be used in a Windows environment. Compiling with the standard MinGW GCC provides no such dependancy. This means however, if you intend to compile with MinGW GCC, you will not have access to POSIX functions such as `fork()` and `exec()`.

For more information on the differences between Cygwin and MinGW, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/771774/1431696).

Comment: I tried installing MinGW and it works fine except it does not support POSIX functions such as fork(). However, it does support POSIX thread such as pthread. So why it supports POSIX pthread but not fork()? I found that from <unistd.h> in /mingw/include directory, there is no fork() declaration in this header file.

Comment: It supports pthread because there exists a Windows implementation of it. There just happen to be Windows implementations of some POSIX functions, such as sockets and pipes. Some implementations (such as sockets) are almost identical to their POSIX counterparts, but others are completely different (like pipes). MinGW is just a port of GCC, it does not attempt to emulate POSIX functions for Windows, because Windows is not a POSIX compliant system. That's where Cygwin comes in. You can think of Cygwin as a port that provides an implementation of POSIX functions in Windows.

Comment: wardd, thanks a lot for explaining in great details. This is very helpful in understanding the diff between MinGW and Cygwin regarding POSIX compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like Cygwin better, it has a lot of installation options and it feels a lot like the terminal you'll find on a Linux machine. It provides a pretty substantial set of Linux-like capabilities, something that Windows fails at miserably.

Comment: Thanks earl3s for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

My offhand thoughts are, if you need cygwin, you need it.  For instance compiling programs that were developed for Unix and have symbolic links and shell scripts in the build system.

If you don't need it, you don't want it. And compiling under linux on a virtual machine is often a better choice than going the cygwin route.

So mingw is perfectly fine.  Works fine, simple to use.

Also: You might consider codelite (www.codelite.org) instead of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gibbon1 for explaining the difference.

Comment: I forgot to mention, codelite comes bundled with mingw.  Click install and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin and Mingw are not interchangeable alternatives. Cygwin is used to compile POSIX API programs, Mingw is used compile Windows API programs.

Chose one or the other depending on what kind program you're going to write.

Answer (score 1):

**Wikipedia Says:**

`MinGW` forked from version 1.3.3 of `Cygwin`. Although both `Cygwin` and `MinGW` can be used to port `UNIX` software to `Windows`, they have different approaches: `Cygwin` aims to provide a complete `POSIX layer` that provides emulations of several system calls and libraries that exist on `Linux`, `UNIX`, and the `BSD` variants. The `POSIX layer` runs on top of `Windows`, sacrificing performance where necessary for compatibility. Accordingly, this approach requires `Windows` programs written with `Cygwin` to run on top of a copylefted compatibility library that must be distributed with the program, along with the program's `source code`. `MinGW` aims to provide native functionality and performance via direct `Windows API calls`. Unlike `Cygwin`, `MinGW` does not require a compatibility layer `DLL` and thus programs do not need to be distributed with `source code`.

Because `MinGW` is dependent upon `Windows API calls`, it cannot provide a full `POSIX API`; it is unable to compile some `UNIX applications` that can be compiled with `Cygwin`. Specifically, this applies to applications that require `POSIX` functionality like `fork()`, `mmap()` or `ioctl()` and those that expect to be run in a `POSIX environment`. Applications written using a `cross-platform library` that has itself been ported to `MinGW`, such as `SDL`, `wxWidgets`, `Qt`, or `GTK+`, will usually compile as easily in `MinGW` as they would in `Cygwin`.

The combination of `MinGW` and `MSYS` provides a small, self-contained environment that can be loaded onto removable media without leaving entries in the registry or files on the computer. `Cygwin` Portable provides a similar feature. By providing more functionality, `Cygwin` becomes more complicated to install and maintain.

It is also possible to `cross-compile Windows applications` with `MinGW-GCC under POSIX systems`. This means that developers do not need a Windows installation with `MSYS` to compile software that will run on `Windows` without `Cygwin`.