# Using cygwin and mingw together

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw

- I want to use **mingw** compiler and some mingw stuff from mingw-get
- I want to use bash and unix tools that shipped with **cygwin**. Because MSYS has some deficiencies.
- I also want to be able to "switch" from using cygwin-gcc to mingw one and back with same bash session if possible.
- I have C:\cygwin and C:\mingw installed and working

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MinGW compiler is available as a Cygwin package. The MinGW-w64 compilers are also available as Cygwin packages. In this way you can use Cygwin for the Linux environment, but also compile executables that do not rely on the Cygwin dll.

I recommend uninstall MinGW completely, and start using Cygwin in this way.