# Matching arbitrary number of digits using grep regex

Tags: regex, grep

I've got a file that has lines in it that look similar as follows

```
data
datalater
983290842
Data387428later
datafhj893724897290384later
4329804928later
```

What I am looking to do is use regex to match any line that starts with data and ends with later AND has numbers in between. Here is what I've concocted so far:

```regex
^[D,d]ata[0-9]*later$
```

However the output includes all datalater lines. I suppose I could pipe the output and grep -v datalater, but I feel like a single expression should do the trick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `*`.

`+` matches at least one or more of the preceding.
`*` matches zero or more.

```
^[Dd]ata[0-9]+later$
```

In grep you need to escape the `+`, and we can use `\d` which is a character class and matches single digits.

```
^[Dd]ata\d\+later$
```

In you example file you also have a line:

```
datafhj893724897290384later
```

This currently will not be matched due to there being letters in-between data and the numbers. We can fix this by adding a `[^0-9]*` to match anything after data until the digits.

Our final command will be:

```
grep '^[Dd]ata[^0-9]*\d\+later$' filename
```

Comment: When using this expression, or @Eric, I get no results on output. Here's what I am using:

    grep ^[D,d]ata[0-9]+later$ filename

Comment: Still no dice with this even as a copy/paste.

Comment: The file contents to have whitespace/line breaks as well

`$ cat test2
datadata

datalater


data98349248later
datadhsd90834092823later`

Comment: If there are whitespaces could you update your example file in the question so I can update the regex. It currently works for the examples you have provided.

Comment: 8 years later, but the tidbit about the + needing be escaped is gold (and quite unintuitive to find by trial and error in a "I need to do this but Linux is not my native environment" situation).

Comment: `\d` is a Perl extension which is generally not portable. Some `grep`s support it, but the POSIX-portable solution is `[[:digit:]]` or simply `[0-9]` if you don't care about locale variations etc.

Answer (score 4):

Using Cygwin, the above commands didn't work. I had to modify the commands given above to get the desired results.

```
$ cat > file.txt <<EOL
> data
> datalater
> 983290842
> Data387428later
> datafhj893724897290384later
> 4329804928later
> EOL
```

I always like to make sure my file has what I expect it to have:

```
$ cat file.txt
data
datalater
983290842
Data387428later
datafhj893724897290384later
4329804928later

$
```

I needed to run Perl-style expressions with the `-P` flag. This meant I couldn't use the `[^0-9]+`, whose necessity  @Tom_Cammann aptly pointed out. Instead, I used `.*` which matches any sequence of characters not matching the next part of the pattern. Here are my command and output.

```
$ grep -P '^[Dd]ata.*\d+later$' file.txt
Data387428later
datafhj893724897290384later

$
```

I wish I could give a better explanation of WHY Perl expressions are needed, but I just know that Cygwin's `grep` works a bit differently.

**System Info**

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 A-1052207 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:29 x86_64 Cygwin
```

**My Results from the previous answers**

```
$ grep '^[Dd]ata[^0-9]*\d\+later$' file2.txt

$ grep '^[Dd]ata\d+later$' file2.txt

$ grep -P '^[Dd]ata[^0-9]*\d\+later$' file2.txt

$ grep -P '^[Dd]ata\d+later$' file2.txt
Data387428later

$
```

Comment: your answer helped me as well though I was using MinGW. according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw the git-bash seems "It depends on the MSYS DLL, which is a fork of the Cygwin DLL" which would explain everything

Comment: This is confused: the backslashed `\+` doesn't make sense with `-P` and `\d` doesn't make sense without it.

Comment: @tripleee , I absolutely agree that it's confused.  Going from an archived copy of this Q&A - available from the WaybackMachine link in my next comment - I see the following (user, final-code) pairs: { (@Tom_Cammann, `grep '^[Dd]ata[^0-9]*\d\+later$' filename`), (@Eric_Galluzzo, `^[Dd]ata\d+later$`) }. I simply tried them all as they appeared in the answers, each with and without the `-P` flag. I imagine the differences might be due to different versions (e.g. a Cygwin version of `grep`), or to `egrep`, `fgrep`, ..., or even something like `alias grep='grep -P'`. If you know, please elucidate.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20220614001142/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926332/matching-arbitrary-number-of-digits-using-grep-regex

Comment: Now, with 6 years more experience, I would do something like `grep '^[Dd]ata[^0-9]*[0-9]\+later$'` or `grep -P '^[Dd]ata[^\d]*\d+later$' dfile`, but I still don't know why neither of the other two answers worked on Cygwin.

Comment: Also confused by this for a long time. Found a regex cheatsheet that compares all these different regex versions: https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html

Answer (score 4):

The "+" syntax only works for extended-regexp, not standard grep.
At least, that's my experience on RHEL.

To use extended-regexp, run egrep or pass "-E" / "--extended-regexp"
Examples...

*Standard grep*

```
echo abc123n1  | grep "abc[0-9]+n1"
<no output>
```

*egrep*

```
echo abc123n1  | egrep "abc[0-9]+n1"
abc123n1
```

*grep with -E*

```
echo abc123n1  | grep -E "abc[0-9]+n1"
abc123n1
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You're matching zero or more digits with the * qualifier.  Try

```
^[Dd]ata\d+later$
```

instead.  You were also finding commas at the beginning of the string (e.g. ",ata1234later").  And \d is a shortcut to finding any digit character.  So I changed those as well.

Comment: I wish this showed output, but doesn't yield any results. See my response to @Tom

Answer (score 1):

You should put a "+" (which means one or several) instead of "*" (which means zero, one or several

Comment: oOps, Tom answered while I was writing an answer among several things, he got it !

Answer (score -1):

**MOTIVATION**

The rest of answers **don't work** on all systems.

---

**️ REQUISITES**

- **grep**
- The option: **--extended-regexp**
- Character groups, aka: **[:group:]**
- Matching one or more of the preceding, aka: **+**
- Optionally setting as starting or ending: **^whatever$**

---

**COMMAND**

`grep --extended-regexp "[[:group:]]+"`

---

**️ GROUPS**

- alnum
- alpha
- blank
- cntrl
- digit
- graph
- lower
- **print**
- punct
- space
- upper
- xdigit

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -Eio "^(data)[0-9]+(later)$"

^[dD]ata=^d later$=r$
```