# Does anyone know how to fix this grep command

Tags: grep

For 1, I can get 101 to 191 to print. How do I include 203 and up as well so that it includes everything from 10 up? For 2, I can get the first set of names starting with an L to print but not the ones in the and 230. Please don't suggest I use something else like awk or sed, I want to know how to do it the way I am currently trying to do it. How can I expand the ranges I am searching in order to include more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the * to grep for repeated Numbers like: `grep "per[0-9]*:L" idfile.txt`

This is a more detailed answer :)
[Regex - Matching arbitrary amount of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926332/regex-matching-arbitrary-amount-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

For 1) since it has to be 10 or more, it needs 2 or more digits, so just use this:

```
grep 'per[0-9]\{2,\}'
```

For 2), just do

```
grep 'per[0-9]*:L'
```

and, of course, you can combine them with

```
grep 'per[0-9]\{2,\}:L'
```