# Difference between cross GCC and MacOSX GCC on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I've just downloaded the eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers I wanted to start a new project.
After choosing the location for the file, I was asked to choose between these two toolchains:
**cross GCC**
and
**MacOSX GCC**.

What's the difference?
Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CDT, Cross GCC is a [cross-compiler project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), one that can build binaries for other platforms/architectures. MacOSX GCC builds only for Mac.

This happens in other operating systems too. If you run CDT in Linux, you must select between [Cross GCC and Linux GCC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76177/difference-between-cross-gcc-and-linux-gcc-toolchain). In Windows, you may select between [Cross GCC, Cygwin GCC and Microsoft Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020338/eclipse-crossgcc)

Comment: Which one should we use? Should we use Cross GCC if we want to sell our product to everyone and mac OS x if we are only supporting MAC?

Comment: If you wanna support only MacOS, you may choose MacOSX GCC. If you wanna build software for other operating systems (e.g. for Windows) or other processoes (e.g. ARM) in your Mac, you will need a cross-compiler.

Comment: Will Cross GCC create an executable that can run on Mac, Windows, and Linux?

Answer (score 2):

As @Jaime said, "In CDT, Cross GCC is a cross-compiler project, one that can build binaries for other platforms/architectures. MacOSX GCC builds only for Mac."

But for guidance on which one to choose, according to [this article](https://mhsamsal.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/cc-in-eclipse-in-mac-os-x/), Cross GCC won't work in Eclipse, so MacOSX GCC is the way to go:

> make sure that you select “MacOSX GCC”. I experienced that selecting
>   the other option (i.e., Cross GCC) does not allow eclipse to run your
>   project. In fact, by choosing this wrong option you’ll get the
>   annoying message of “Launch fail. Binaries are missing” when you try
>   to run your project.

Comment: To use "Cross GCC" you must install different packages than the required for "MacOSX GCC". Usually, when you install GCC in Mac (or any other operating system), you install the native compiler but not the cross-compiler. For instance, If you install GCC in your Mac using Xcode, you will not install the cross-compiler and you cannot use the "Cross GCC" option.

Comment: To install a cross-compiler GCC in a Mac, you may use [osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) or some [homebrew formulas](https://blog.filippo.io/easy-windows-and-linux-cross-compilers-for-macos/)