# Git Bash operate with cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

I installed Git-Bash but I won't be able to access all the tools(vim,vimdiff) that I can access with Cygwin. Can that be set in one of the Git config files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git bash, and related tools in msysgit package, are pure Windows executables.

That's why you cannot run Cygwin tools into Git bash, since these are *not* completely windows programs (they need the `cygwin.dll`, see @fvu comment below).

If you want to use Git with Cygwin tools, you have to install the git package for Cygwin.

Comment: Cygwin-compiled programs are Windows programs, but they depend on an emulation of certain POSIX features as provided by the cygwin dll.  More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw).  But that doesn't change your conclusion.

Comment: Then why is it possible to run Cygwin tools from cmd.exe (which is a pure Windows executable), but not Git bash?

Comment: Then why is it possible to run Cygwin `rsync` from Git Bash, after I added `C:\cygwin64\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable? See answer below by Keith Tyler.

Answer (score 4):

You might just need to add the cygwin bin directory to your $PATH variable in git bash.

Despite what everyone else seems to think they know, Git Bash is actually pretty much repackaged Cygwin. Viz: https://github.com/msysgit/msys/tree/master/winsup/cygwin

Answer (score 0):

If you add theCygwin `bin` directory to your `$PATH` variable in git bash, make sure to use Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

Utilities run via the `run_command()` API were not spawned correctly on Cygwin, when the paths to them are given as a full path with backslashes.

See [commit 05ac858](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05ac8582bc722c8bd3ab7a0cafa681bec198a06d) (27 Mar 2020) by [Andras Kucsma (`r0mai`)](https://github.com/r0mai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d01b722](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d01b722b7a077202c82902f49c48cb8081c696ef), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`run-command`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05ac8582bc722c8bd3ab7a0cafa681bec198a06d): trigger PATH lookup properly on Cygwin
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andras Kucsma</sup>
>
> On Cygwin, the codepath for POSIX-like systems is taken in [`run-command.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05ac8582bc722c8bd3ab7a0cafa681bec198a06d/run-command.c)::start_command(). The `prepare_cmd()` helper function is called to decide if the command needs to be looked up in the PATH. The logic there is to do the PATH-lookup if and only if it does not have any slash '/' in it. If this test passes we end up attempting to run the command by appending the string after each colon-separated component of PATH.
>
> The Cygwin environment supports both Windows and POSIX style paths, so both forwardslahes '/' and back slashes '\' can be used as directory separators for any external program the user supplies.
>
> Examples for path strings which are being incorrectly searched for in the PATH instead of being executed as is:

```
"C:\Program Files\some-program.exe" - "a\b\c.exe"
```

> To handle these, the `PATH` lookup detection logic in `prepare_cmd()` is taught to know about this Cygwin quirk, by introducing `has_dir_sep(`path) helper function to abstract away the difference between true POSIX and Cygwin systems.