# What's the need of MSYS with MinGW in Windows

Tags: c++, c, mingw, msys

I saw that MinGW has a makefile too which is not supported in NetBeans/Eclipse. Why? And why MSYS? I also heard MSYS is Unix like env, so why do I need it for Windows programming?

Comment: See [What is the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put msys is a unix/linux like enviorenment on windows. means you can run your program in unix/linux which you're making on windows

Answer (score 1):

As a background check the question I indicated in the comments [What is the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw). Check also [msys vs cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627/msys-vs-cygwin)

> i saw that mingw has a make file too which is not supported in netbeans/eclipse. why?

Not sure about that: mingw is a compiler, has nothing to do with the Make program or its Makefile format. You can choose to build with other make-like systems.

> and why msys? i also heard msys is unix like env, so why do i need it for windows programming?

msys is a small subset of the tools you typically find in a unix-like environment, complementing the mingw compiler. If you ever used them you would not be asking why you need them (e.g. *why would I need a bask/ksh shell when I have `cmd` already in windows?*)