# Cygwin MinGW package vs. standalone MinGW

Tags: cygwin, mingw, posix, mingw-w64

I would like to have a POSIX environment in Windows (to be used as a system shell) and at the same time produce native Windows executables. One option in the past was to install Cygwin and MinGW and possibly call MinGW compiler binaries from Cygwin.

Now an x64  MinGW is available straight as a Cygwin  package and there are some [blogs](http://go.kblog.us/2012/09/setting-up-mingw64-with-cygwin.html) documenting how to get them  play nicely together.

Before adopting  this solution, I would like to know how and if the Cygwin  package is different from a standalone  MinGW-w64. Specifically which one is more efficient in producing native Win64 exe's? Is Cygwin  package itself based on native executables, or is an extension to its gcc compilers?

### Update

Some of you miscomprehended  this question:

*I am not interested in the difference between  Cygwin and  MinGW  at all.*

(and by the way, on the  very home  page of  [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) their main concern is to show how they differentiate from Cygwin)

My question instead is very specific: I am interested in the difference between a specific **Cygwin package** and its standalone version.
This package happens to be "mingw64-x86_64", which is  split in several dependencies files, of which  the most relevant is perhaps "mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core".

Sorry, but references found in some comments are utterly wrong with respect to what is asked here: first they address  to Cygwin as a whole and not the mentioned package; secondly they refer to a rather old MinGW version, significantly different from that mentioned here (see here for the [differences](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Feature%20list/)).
Someone also mentions MSYS2, which is a modern  Cygwin fork, but again I am not interested to Cygwin (as whole), but to the said package.

Some of you might not be aware of this package, and in fact, if you google for "mingw64-x86_64", you don't find anything relevant for the Cygwin package, and most likely land on the general version, and this is why I am posting here.

Comment: Closely related, perhaps a duplicate: [What's the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/771756/183120)

Comment: Use [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/) for the shell emulation, and MinGW to produce native Windows executables; using Cygwin would produce a executable that depends on cygwin1.dll which emulates lot of POSIX behaviour on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Install Cygwin and the package `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core`.

---

> if the Cygwin package is different from a standalone MinGW-w64

They are the same.

---

1. MinGW - this is the project that can be found at mingw.org and
   sourceforge.net/projects/mingw. This project has been superceded by the MSYS2
   and MinGW-w64 projects.
2. Cygwin environment - Unix-like environment, namely Bash.
3. Cygwin compilers - these are the packages `gcc-core` and `cygwin32-gcc-core`
   which include the files `x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe` and
   `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe`. These compilers create programs that rely on
   `cygwin1.dll`.
4. [MSYS2 environment](http://msys2.github.io) - Unix-like environment, namely Bash. This is an
   update to the MSYS environment provided by the old MinGW project.
5. MinGW-w64 compilers - these are the packages `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` and
   `mingw64-i686-gcc-core` which include the files `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`
   and
   `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`. These compilers create Windows native
   programs that do not rely on `cygwin1.dll`.

[What do the C compilers on Cygwin generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27344540/#27349767)