# What do the C compilers on Cygwin generate?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw

Based on the output of the identify-compilers.sh script below, it appears that the following C compilers are available on Cygwin. Those labeled "Cygwin" require the cygwin1.dll file to be available.

What is the difference between the "pc" and "w64" compilers?

Why is there no x86_64-pc-mingw-gcc.exe executabe?

Are there any other C compilers available?

```
/usr/bin/gcc.exe                        64-bit  Cygwin
/usr/bin/i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe         32-bit  Cygwin
/usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-gcc.exe        32-bit
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe       32-bit
/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe       64-bit  Cygwin
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe     64-bit

$ cat identify-compilers.sh
#!/bin/bash
for c in $(ls -1 /usr/bin/*gcc.exe); do
    echo === compiler: $c
    $c -o hello.exe hello.c
    objdump -p hello.exe | grep -i "cygwin"
    objdump -p hello.exe | grep -i "64$"
    rm hello.exe
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `gcc` is just a hard link to `x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc`
2. `x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc` and `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc` are as you have said the
   Cygwin compilers, that is to say the compilers that create programs that rely
   on `cygwin1.dll`
3. `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` are compilers provided
   by the [Mingw-w64 project](http://mingw-w64.org)
4. `i686-pc-mingw32-gcc` is a compiler provided by the [MinGW project](http://mingw.org)

You may be wondering, why the two Mingw projects? Well the Mingw-w64 project was
started because MinGW [refused to adopt](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/History) the 64-bit compiler. Between this
and the starting of the [MSYS2 project](http://msys2.sourceforge.net), I consider the MinGW project
obsolete.