# cmake MSYS Makefiles generator missing

Tags: cmake, msys

I have cmake 3.2.3 installed via pacman.  I get an error when I try to use it from a msys64 shell:

```
$ cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
CMake Error: Could not create named generator MSYS Makefiles
```

cmake --help does not list it as an available generator.

I do see there is an MSYS.cmake in /usr/share/cmake-3.2.3/Modules/Platform.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 30):

Instead of installing the `cmake` package, I think you need to install `mingw-w64-i686-cmake` (or the 64-bit version `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`).

Comment: I also had to run `${MINGW_PREFIX}/bin/cmake` instead of just `cmake` to make it work.

Comment: As of 2019, neither the 32-bit or 64-bit versions of mingw64 exist in the Cygwin installer and I can't find them via `apt-cyg`.

Comment: @Hashim this question is about MinGW, not Cygwin. My understanding is that they are completely separate systems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw

Comment: It's actually about MSYS Makefiles, which is the Cmake generator Cygwin relies on when using MinGW-64 packages to build (a common use case, as it's more reliable than building with the native Cygwin packages). My comment above doesn't change your answer, I just wanted to get it out in the open for those using Cygwin.

Comment: Swapping to mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake (3.25.2) fixed it for me as well, after removing the old cmake (3.25.1-1). It added quite a few previously missing generators.

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same message when trying to run cmake in the **MSYS** shell. Use a **MinGW Shell** (for instance MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell) instead.

Comment: Personally, I just add the MinGW bin directory to my path in my MSYS user's home dir via .bash_profile. This lets me use MSYS and specify which MinGW I want. I then use MSYS for just about everything terminal side.

Answer (score 2):

**If you compile native Windows binaries on Linux with MinGW**

The `MinGW` and `MSYS` generators are only available on Windows based distributions. See `#ifdef` in [cmake.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L68):

> ```
> #if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
> ```

If you're cross-compiling use one of the available MinGW toolchains. See e.g. ["How to use MinGW to cross compile software for Windows"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/cross_compiling/Mingw) chapter in CMake's wiki.

**If you compile Windows binaries on Windows with MinGW**

On my Windows PC I only have one CMake installation (the normal MSI Windows Installer with CMake directory added to PATH environment), which works from standard CMD shells and from my MSYS shells.

So in this case there is no need to install a special MinGW version of CMake (like e.g. for CygWin).

But I've rebuild CMake from source with MinGW-w64 several times lately to test some performance optimizations of `cmake.exe` and it did not work out-of-the-box. To work around the linker errors I've added `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition"` like recommended [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=76798) and the resulting `cmake.exe` still supports the "MSYS Makefiles" generator.

So yes, there is - as you have commented - most probably something wrong with the pacman build.

Comment: Well, it was built with msys/mingw so it is a windows distribution.  Are you saying the generator list is hard-coded in the executable?  I guess that would imply that there is something wrong with the pacman build.

Comment: @ScottThibault Yes, the generator list is hardcoded it the executable and depends for which host OS CMake is build for. And your installation path `/usr/share/cmake-3.2.3` does suggest you are using/running a Linux distribution. On what host OS do you execute CMake?

Comment: @ScottThibault I've updated my answer to cover the possible host OS variants.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the pacman build is just broken, so I've resolved this issue by installing the Windows version of CMake from cmake.org with the msi installer.