# How to install TBB on Windows and get it work with Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, intel, tbb

I want to install Intel's Thread Building Blocks on Windows and get it to work with the Eclipse IDE and C++. I've been new to the whole C, build from source, make, cmake, cygwin and other stuff.

What I've tried so far:

- Load the TBB packages and source and try to include it in Eclipse
- Try to 'make' TBB from source but only got Error 2 from GNUWin32make
- Tried many tutorials, tips and much more that I don't remember any more

How can I do this?

*Win 10 - 64bit, Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0, cygwin 2.8.2, Compiler: mingw*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [Release_Notes.txt](https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/tbb_2017/doc/Release_Notes.txt), a library doesn't have a Cygwin support. However you have several cases:

1. Use Visual Studio and binary package
2. Use Linux (if you really need GCC)
3. Use Mingw without(!) Cygwin ([difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/792142/2230159)). Building library from source code should work perfect in this case.
4. Port library to cygwin (it's a non-trivial but real solution)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried to build with Mingw but still got errors. I got Mingw in my path variable and try the make command in the source folder of tbb. Make quits with the errors that it can't find "./build/detect.js". But the file is there.

Comment: Try to `cd src` and `make tbb tbbmalloc compiler=gcc stdver=c++11`
If it doesn't work -- provide an output

Comment: Hi, I've tried but got the same error.
`C:\Users\Leon\Documents\tbb\src>make tbb tbbmalloc compiler=gccstdver=c++11
The command "\"cscript /nologo /E:jscript ../build/detect.js  /arch gccstdver=c++11\""" is spelled wrong or could not be find.
The command "\"cscript /nologo /E:jscript ../build/detect.js  /runtime gccstdver=c++11\""" is spelled wrong or could not be find.
../build/common.inc:73: *** Architecture not detected.  Stop.`

Should I try to delete all compilers, cygwin and all the other stuff and reinstall it? If I get it right I onle need Mingw?

Comment: 1. You lose space between `gcc` and `stdver`

2. Try to execute `where g++` and `g++ -v`

Answer (score 0):

lost the space by copiying here.

> where g++
>
> C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
>   C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
>
> g++ -v 
>   Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\
>   Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32 Configured with:
>   ../../../src/gcc-7.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw710/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw710/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident
>   -I/c/mingw710/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS='
>   -I/c/mingw710/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident
>   -L/c/mingw710/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw710/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib ' Thread model: posix gcc version 7.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by
>   MinGW-W64 project)

Comment: Weird, I checked same version on my PC and it works; The main difference is: I keep compilers "near" the drive root to prevent spaces and long paths (env. variables has some limits). I guess you should check your environment(clean-up it) and source compiler directly e.g: `set PATH=C\bin\mingw-w64\bin;%PATH%` before use
Also check what version of TBB do you try to use